# Is it ok to re categorize my variables this way?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a 2^3 factorial design, where the dependent variable is binary, and the three independents are binary and I care about interactions.

I've seen that you can use logistic regression, but I feel this doesn't fully answer my question.   Instead of having y~ a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc, can I just have y~as.factor(factors), where I recode a to be 1, b to be 2.....   abc to be 8.   Then I can use kruskal Wallis or something to serve as like an ANOVA?

My data is unbalanced, and obviously not normally distributed, but observations are independent.  and although I like the logistic regression, I feel like I need an additional step to determine that effect BC is statistically different from effect AC (for example).  I want the multiple comparisons.

Help please :)

Comment: Seems like your question ought to be on how to estimate/test contrasts within a logistic regression model.

Comment: That actually is my question.  I can't figure out how to best test whether or not any of these combinations are truly different from each other.  And I know logistic regression will control for factors in the model but is really comparing to the intercept.  I'd rather not test each comparison separately.